# Running a function of a class from a file displayed by that class

Tags: php, function, class, require-once

I have a class called `CouponGenerator`. This class has two functions:

```
public function generateCoupon() {
   // CODE HERE
}
```

and

```
public function loadCoupon() {
   require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/templates/couponDiv.php');
}
```

Inside the `couponDiv.php` file I have some markup:

```
<?php
$coupon = new CouponGenerator();
?>

<div class="fbsc_container" id="outer_div">
    <div class="fbsc_container" id="fbsc_content">
        <h4 class="fbsc_text" id="fbsc_header"> [HEADER] </h4>
        <p class="fbsc_text" id="fbsc_inside_text"> <?php $coupon->generateCoupon(); ?> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sadly `$coupon->generateCoupon();` does not activate the `generateCoupon()` function for me at all. I am not sure if I am calling it correctly from inside of the `couponDiv.php` file.

**How could I make it work correctly?**

Comment: does `generateCoupon` return the coupon or echo it?

Comment: It does, and the function is written properly, because I've checked it by directly launching it in the main file. The problem is only when I try to launch that function from inside `couponDiv.php` which is required as stated in the code in my post.

Comment: The problem is that you completely missed the point of object oriented programming. Why do you even have a class if you're using it as a regular, procedural piece of spaghetti code? Basically - you can't use it that way. You should be getting some errors while doing so - and you should post those errors so we can tell you why you're doing it wrong and how to do it properly.

Comment: It occurs that I simply forgot to write 'echo' before the function. Now it works properly.

Comment: You're still better off scrapping the class since there's nothing object oriented in your code and use traditional procedural approach. It'll hurt less to play with it.

Comment: Sure, right now there is no difference between the OOP and structural programming here, but later I will add some more functionality to it so it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, forgot to put 'echo' before calling the function.

Case closed.